# How do get submodule sha from main project sha

Tags: git

I have a git commit sha from the main project. How do I get the latest sha for each submodule at that main project commit sha? For example, if the main project sha is A, I want to get the latest git commit sha for each submodule when the code at commit sha A was committed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be, assuming the hash you have is a commit:

```
git ls-tree <main-sha1>^{tree} path/to/submodule
```

That should give you output like:

```
160000 commit <submodule-sha1> path/to/submodule
```

You would have to do this for each submodule, and it might get tricky if your submodules have changed significantly through out the history of your project. But I suppose you could use:

```
git show <main-sha1>:.gitmodules
```

as a starting point to discover what submodules exist for that particular commit, and where they are attached.